# Существование слова симуклярность

Tags: выбор-слов, словообразование

Пример употребления в интернете нашёл только один. Почему? Ведь из определения существительного ясно, что слово обозначает. Есть какие-то ограничения, о которых я не знаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему?

Потому что слово напечатали с ошибкой. А слова с ошибками хоть и попадаются в сети, но пока ещё значительно реже.